# Remove values from excel sheet using python

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I have an excel workbook which consists of a sheet having 4 columns viz. (traveller no., from, to, medium) and containing the routes travellers took to reach their destination. The traveller number can be repeated based on the number of changes a traveller made to reach their destination.

My question is, how do I only keep the relevant data while removing all other cell values having 'No information' using python.

Example worksheet:

| traveller no. | from | to | medium |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | manchester | london | train |
| 2 | derby | coventry | train |
| 2 | derby | coventry | train |
| 3 | liverpool | manchester | No information |
| 3 | manchester | london | flight |
| 3 | london | wembley | bus |
| 4 | 4. No information | wolverhampton | 4. No information |
| 5 | 5. No information | 5. No information | 5. No information |
| 6 | 6. No information | 6. No information | 6. No information |
| 7 | 7. No information | 7. No information | 7. No information |
| 8 | 8. No information | 8. No information | 8. No information |

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to load the data frame using pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('path/to/file.xlsx')
df
    traveller no.            from              to          medium
0               1      manchester          london           train
1               2           derby        coventry           train
2               2           derby        coventry           train
3               3       liverpool      manchester  No information
4               3      manchester          london          flight
5               3          london         wembley             bus
6               4  No information   wolverhampton  No information
7               5  No information  No information  No information
8               6  No information  No information  No information
9               7  No information  No information  No information
10              8  No information  No information  No information
```

After it, you need to specify the exact columns that you want to check and replace 'No information' with a more common NaN:

```
df = df[df != 'No information']
df
    traveller no.        from             to  medium
0               1  manchester         london   train
1               2       derby       coventry   train
2               2       derby       coventry   train
3               3   liverpool     manchester     NaN
4               3  manchester         london  flight
5               3      london        wembley     bus
6               4         NaN  wolverhampton     NaN
7               5         NaN            NaN     NaN
8               6         NaN            NaN     NaN
9               7         NaN            NaN     NaN
10              8         NaN            NaN     NaN
```

It will replace all instances of 'No information' with NaN. Now you can use more widespread approach of dropping NaN values with `dropna()` function:

```
df = df.dropna(subset=['from', 'to', 'medium'])
df
      traveller no.        from        to  medium
0              1  manchester    london   train
1              2       derby  coventry   train
2              2       derby  coventry   train
4              3  manchester    london  flight
5              3      london   wembley     bus
```

The keyword `subset` will remove all rows with at least one missing value in the specified columns. If you want a bit different behavior, please, address the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, just a follow up question, what would be the way to go if every No Information was prefaced by the traveller number? e.g.
3. No information | 3. No information | 3. No information
4. No information | 4. no Information | 4. No information|
etc. 

I have made the changes to the question as well and would be grateful if you could help me with this.

Comment: In this case, you will have to use `replace` method: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html. 
It will look something like this: 
`df.replace("No Information", "", regex=True)`

Answer (score 0):

I am assuiming you are using the pandas library. In that case, you can loop through column titles, and the column that has the string: "No information", will be used to remove the entire row.

```
df = df[df["from|to|medium"].str.contains("No information") == False]
```

If the code doesn;t work, try playing with the below part (i.e only add "from").

```
"from|to|medium"
```

P.s the variable named df is the dataframe that you need to select.